# how fix this error:Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: javascript, loops, three.js, gltf, variable-length-array

I am creating a website loading gltf 3d models.I want to load more models using loop.

```js
const loader = new GLTFLoader()
//.setPath( 'models/gltf/DamagedHelmet/glTF/' );
      .setPath( 'resources/' );
const resourceData = ["Learning Bee1","Learning Bee2","Learning Bee3"];
//const l = resourceData.length;

for(let i=0; i<resourceData.length;i++){
    let oResource = resourceData[i];
    let sModelName = oResource + ".gltf";
    loader.load( sModelName, function ( gltf ) {

        gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {

            if ( child.isMesh ) {

                roughnessMipmapper.generateMipmaps( child.material );

            }

        });
    });

    scene.add( gltf.scene );

    roughnessMipmapper.dispose();

    render();

}

});
```

When I run this,shown below error.how fix this?

three.module.js:38723 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
at three.module.js:38723

Comment: Looking at the code if you would indent properly you will see that `scene.add( gltf.scene );` is outside the code where `gltf` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your code indentation is a bit sloppy, and it's making you commit mistakes that could be avoided with cleaner code.

1. You're calling `gltf.scene` outside of the brackets, where it doesn't exist:

```js
loader.load( sModelName, function ( gltf ) {
    // gltf exists here
});

// gltf does not exist here
scene.add( gltf.scene );
```

2. You dispose the `roughnessMipmapper` before using it. Keep in mind that the callback function in the loader takes some time to be executed, since it's waiting to finish loading your asset.

```js
loader.load( sModelName, function ( gltf ) {
    // 2. This happens later, after assets load
    roughnessMipmapper.generateMipmaps( child.material );
});

// 1. This gets called first
roughnessMipmapper.dispose();
```